# Worst case scenario: Copying an order?

Tags: orders, database

the worst case scenario happened: Google indexed a staging installation that was temporarily online and a customer ordered in this staging area.

How complicated is it to copy the order from one installation to another, as long as the id is still open in the target system? What do I have to export/import to transfer the order?

I know, it's a "you should never do that" situation, but I need to transfer that order somehow.

Thanks for your help

Arne

Comment: This has happened to me before.  We opted to rebuild the order on the live system.  Lucky for us, the user paid via PayPal and we were not in sandbox mode.  The customer never knew the difference, because we shipped it in the dev system, so they would see the same order number.  Also, they were checking out as a guest, so they would never see the new number in the order history either.  We can still find it by their name or email address if need be.

Answer (score 1):

There are many modules that can import and export order data for you:

Here is one of them:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dataflow-batch-import-export-orders-to-csv-xml.html

This is just one example, if you google 'magento import export orders' you can see more mods that do this.

Regarding payment:

This is a bit trickier, since Magento does not save the CC number (only last four in Enterprise), you might need to contact the customer for that.